Scroll functionality using mousewheel not working in wpf xaml
I have a usercontrol in wpf xaml which displays image in grid. But im not able to scroll with my mouse scroll wheel and scroll bar does not move with my mouse scroll wheel.
I can move scroll bar only by clicking on it and dragging. Also my view is not changing dynamically when i move my scroll bar .Only when it settles down at a certain position, view of grid images change.
How to fix these issues?
Here is what i have tried :
<UserControl x:Class="ImageGridView.View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Name="ParentUserControl"
             d:DesignHeight="350" d:DesignWidth="350" Loaded="OnLoad" Unloaded="OnUnload">        
    <Grid Name="TheGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl Name="myItemControl" ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayedImages, Mode=OneWay}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <views:GridPanelNew Rows="{Binding ViewData.Rows, Mode=OneWay}" Columns="{Binding ViewData.Columns, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <views:ImagesTemplate Margin="5" Name="ImagesTemplate" SourceImage="{Binding Images, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <ScrollBar Name="ScrollBarEngagement" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Minimum="0" ViewportSize="{Binding ViewData.ViewportSize, Mode=OneWay}" Maximum ="{Binding ViewData.MaxScroll, Mode=OneWay}" SmallChange="1" Scroll="ScrollView" Margin="0">
            <ScrollBar.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.PreviewMouseDown" >
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.PreviewMouseUp">
                </EventTrigger>
            </ScrollBar.Triggers>
        </ScrollBar>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>      
</UserControl>


Can you please create a minimal reproducible example and remove all unnecessary code? If removing your custom controls breaks the erroneous behavior and you have to add them to replicate the error then also add the source code of these controls. In general, you should not wrap the ItemsControl into a ScrollViewer, but the ItemsPresenter of the ItemsControl. You want to scroll the items and not the control.

You should back out your ScrollViewer "modifications" and see what happens; I find it works quite well "as is": Panning, scrolling and zooming; by mouse, touch (tap, swipe, pinch and  drag), and "command and control" (i.e. buttons).

@BionicCode How do i modify to scroll items ? I dont get it

This fixed my issue :
<views:GridPanelNew Rows="{Binding ViewData.Rows, Mode=OneWay}" Columns="{Binding ViewData.Columns, Mode=OneWay}" PreviewMouseWheel="GridPanelNew MouseWheel"/>
And handling Mouse wheel change delta value in my xaml.cs
